# Permanent redirect from example.com/ to https://www.example.com/dir/

Tags: redirect, nginx, microservices

I have some software build with microservice philosophy. On of them - which was hosted on `example.com/` became useless so I want the user to be redirected to `example.com/dir/` where another service is hosted. The most popular solution on `StackOverflow` is to use the following code in the configuration file:

```
location = / {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host/dir/;
}
```

or

```
location = / {
    return 301 https://$http_host/dir/;
}
```

They both fail on my server - the server returns `503 - to many computations`. The stacktrace shows, that there is no rule-infinite-rule so this code might be returned by `load-balancer`.

Is there any other well working solution for this issue? `StackOverflow` and `ServerFault` have just been carefully searched for the last 3 days by me and any solution worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching together with my teammates it has occured, that not only `return 301 url;` succesfuly redirects user. Although the documentation says avoid using `rewrite` what has worked is:

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/$ https://$http_host/dir/ permantent;
    ...
}
```

The `permantent` statement is responsible for acting as a regular redirection.

**Important:**
In nginx `^` is the begining of a regular expression and of the incomming string and `$` sign is a normal `regex` sign which stands for `theEndOfString`. So  regex `^/$` means match `iff` url equals `/`.

**Credits:**

Hopefully this will save one's weekend-time and money.

Answer (score -2):

The = sign is invalid.

```
location / {
    return 301 https://$http_host/dir/;
}
```

But that will end in a redirect loop, so be more specific:

```
location ~ ^[/]?$ {
    return 301 https://$http_host/dir/;
}
```

Comment: It's not - the `=` sign means that the match must be exact. Google documentation.

Comment: Nope. Your regex would match /dir/ also. Each url would get redirected. Your answer is copied from another similar topic.

Comment: The regex matches only root, with or without slash, so `domain.com` and `domain.com/` - nothing behind it.

Comment: only if you would provide = sign. Otherwise it matches also /dir/, /dir/dir2/ etc.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: @xenteros - As a warning, please don't insult others via improper edits: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12822335